# how to update the multiple row based on select value in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

First I have insert the data from  bb_IssueReq table to @transaction , after that i want update the multiple row based on selected SQL query trans_id . Now the result only can update the single row. do you have any suggestion to improve the SQL query for update the multiple row in @transaction. The SQL query was attached below.

```
DECLARE @transaction table (
        id bigint,invoice_no varchar(50),[time] datetime,
        trans_id bigint,cust_hp varchar(50),
        cardno varchar(20),username varchar(200),
        bb_value money,bb_amount money,
        key_amt money, charge money,
        bb_type int,pay_amt money
    )

    INSERT INTO @transaction
       (id, invoice_no, [time], trans_id, cust_hp, cardno, username, 
            bb_value, bb_amount, key_amt, charge)

        SELECT top 20
            id as issue_idx,
            invoice_no as [invoice_no],
            Updated as [timestamp],
            id as trans_id,
            hp as cust_hp,
            card_no as cardno,
            name as username,
            b_value as bb_value,
            amount as bb_amount,
            Amount as key_amt,
            charr as charge,
        FROM bb_IssueReq(NOLOCK)
        where status = 0 and id ='1211'

        declare @trans bigint, @bbtype int, @payout money

        SELECT top 20
            @trans =A.trans_id,
            @bbype =B.type,
            @payout =Cast(C.amt * C.rate) 
        FROM bb_IssueReq(NOLOCK) A
        inner join vw_req B on A.trans_id = B.id 
        inner join trant C on C.payroll_tranid = B.redeem_id
        where A.status = 0 and A.id = '1211'

            ********* update query  based on @trans *********

        update @transaction
        set bb_type = @bbtype,
            pay_amt = @payout
        where  trans_id = @trans 

        select * from @transaction
```

Comment: The first thing to do is to STOP splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). And if you do use it (can't possibly need it IMO) then at least use the current syntax and not the deprecated syntax.

Comment: Whitespace doesn't cost, you know. And `NOLOCK` is not a "go-faster" switch, it's a "give-incorrect-results" switch. It's unclear why you need the variables and table variables anyway, the whole thing could be one big joined `update`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do an UPDATE statement with JOIN in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

It would be the same as any other UPDATE of a join

```
UPDATE d
SET d.columnInDest = s.columnInSource, ...
FROM
  destinationTable d JOIN sourceTable s ON ...
WHERE
  ...
```

The join co-ordinates the rows between your @transaction table (and it is a table, effectively) and your other table, then the update specifies how the data is copied. It can be as complex as any other update of a single table (you can update d with the results of sums performed on s's columns etc)

I'm not really sure which table is your source and which is your destination, hence the generic advice